# Fullpage.js is showing next section on tab inside a form

Tags: javascript, forms, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js, and on my contact page I have a form on my second section. The third section is the footer.

When I focus on the first input of the form and press tab, it sends me to the next section or another link on the page, but not the next input.

What could be a solution for this?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: please check this thread. it might help you.
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1237

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But as you can see in that thread, there still is no good solution.

Comment: I now used `$('a, input, select, button, textarea').prop('tabIndex', -1);` to not be able to use TAB all togheter. But now I would like to only use TAB in 1 form per page. How could I enable the tabbing for that form? I tried giving those inputs a class, and then using the previous script to give those inputs a tabindex of 1 or 2, but that is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be using the latest fullpage.js version 3.0.2.
The issue was fixed in fullpage.js 2.9.6 as detailed [in this comment](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/1237#issuecomment-358009874).

The only scenarios that are not working are:

- Focusable elements inside iframes
- Focusable elements outside fullpage.js container.